# ios google drive sdk version

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I applied `ios` google drive `sdk` long time ago.
but I do not know `sdk` version.

and I want to update `sdk`, if there is some changes.
but

https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client

https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart

these site does not have any change log or current version information.

question :

1. How to know `sdk` version in my app.

   - `GTLService` requestUserAgent => is this method right?
2. how to know `sdk` change log(deprecated api..)

Comment: update your pod ,u will able to see current version in terminal

Comment: ohh then download current sdk and take files from that to use it